# Ansible module amazon.aws and the aws_service_ip_ranges lookup plugin

Tags: ansible, yaml, syntax-error

In testing a cloudfront WAF instance, I need the list of IPs or ranges of IPs that Cloudfront is using for our instance so that we can white list them in our firewall. It appears that the Ansible module collection `amazon.aws` and the lookup plugin `aws_service_ip_ranges` will do that, however I'm very stuck on getting syntax correct in the yaml.

I have read the [docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/collections_using.html) [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html), [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/index.html), and [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/aws_service_ip_ranges_lookup.html#ansible-collections-amazon-aws-aws-service-ip-ranges-lookup), and I still do not quite understand how to successfully lookup the IPs used. I need a tangible example of how to write a yaml to get those IPs. Using the examples given in the documentation has not worked as, again, I am unclear about the syntax of those examples.

Here is what I have right now which returns a syntax error at the `vars:` line.

```
---
- hosts: <hostname>
  remote_user: ansible
  collections: amazon.aws
  tasks:
  - name:  Get IP Range
    plugin: aws_service_ip_ranges
      vars:
       cloudfront_ranges: "{{ lookup('aws_service_ip_ranges', region 'us-east-1', service 'CLOUDFRONT', wantlist True) }}"
  - name: "use list return option and iterate as a loop"
    debug: msg="{% for cidr in cloudfront_ranges %}{{ cidr }} {% endfor %}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to go simpler, do less in the playbook. I combined the `collections` and `plugins` items into one. Moved `vars` to the same tab level as `collections`.

```
---
- hosts: <hostname>
  collections: 
   - amazon.aws.aws_service_ip_ranges
  remote_user: ansible
  vars: 
    cloudfront_ranges: "{{ lookup('aws_service_ip_ranges', service='CLOUDFRONT', wantlist=True) }}"
  tasks:
  - name: use list return option and iterate as a loop
    debug: msg="{% for cidr in cloudfront_ranges %}{{ cidr }} {% endfor %}"
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.